# Angular2 Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'XXX'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing an Angular2 application and I have the following component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CourseAdminService} from "../shared/course-admin.service";
import {Course} from "../shared/course";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-admin-list',
  templateUrl: './course-admin-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-admin-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseAdminListComponent implements OnInit {

  courses: Course[] = [];
  keyword = "";

  constructor(private courseAdminService: CourseAdminService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMore();
  }

  reset() {
    this.courses = [];
    this.loadMore();
  }

  loadMore() {
    let since: Date = null;
    let before: Date = null;

    let len = this.courses.length;
    if (len > 1000) {
      since = this.courses[0].creationTime;
      before = this.courses[len - 1].creationTime;
    }

    let subscription = this.courseAdminService.get(since, before, this.keyword)
      .subscribe(courses => {
        this.courses = this.courses.concat(courses);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      });
  }
}
```

And I have the following interface:

```
export interface Course {
  id: string;
  nameEn: string;
  nameAr: string;
  trainer: string;
  type: string;
  country: string;
  city: string;
  level: string;
  creationTime: Date;
}
```

The problem here is that when I try to compile the app (using angular@cli) it gives me the error: `Property 'creationTime' does not exist on type 'Course'`, and as you can see above the `creationTime` property is indeed a part of the interface. So can anybody tell me whats the issue here?

Comment: Have you compiled the ts files to js files?

Comment: what is the return value of your `courseAdminService.get` function. if that wont return a Course he could complain. but it would be good to know the line number where he thinks this happens

Comment: @echonax I'm using the `ng serve` command from anglar-cli which does that automatically

Comment: @Daniel it is returning `Observable<Course[]>` and the line numbers are for the `since = this.courses[0].creationTime; before = this.courses[len - 1].creationTime;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that whenever I want to modify an interface like adding a new property or even create a new interface, I have to stop the `ng serve` command and rerun it again.